# How can I use nohup command to get root access of the target machine?

Tags: privilege-escalation, ctf

I am playing ctf and I have gained access to the target machine but not as root. I can see nohup utility has root access on the machine and I used this command to get the root access but that did not work:

```
nohup /bin/sh -p -c “sh -p <$(tty) >$(tty) 2>$(tty)”

-bash: $(tty)”: Permission denied
```

Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: *"I can see nohup utility has a root access of the machine"* - what makes you think so?

Comment: Your double quotes seem to be of the wrong kind, but maybe that's a copy paste error. What about just `nohup id` (assuming nohup is SUID root, in sudoers or something like that)?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich because when I used ls -al command on the target machine I got this result -rw------- 1 root  dlink  122 Sep 30 01:05 nohup.out. So, I am looking for a command which can give me root access using nohup utility.

Comment: @domen I am beginner and started to playing ctf and this is first machine I am trying to crack and yes nohup is one of the SUID and SGid file I found when enumeration.